# Pushdown automaton that accepts $a^{2k} b^{3k}$, without multiple pop

Tags: pushdown-automata

I am trying to create a PDA with at most 7 states that accepts the following language over the alphabet $\Sigma = \{a,b\}$:

$$
\{a^{2k}b^{3k}  \mid k \geq 0\}
$$

The tricky part is that multiple push allowed but multiple pop is not allowed. I was able to find the easy solution when multi push/pop is allowed. I am looking for solutions where ***multi push/pop is not allowed*** and ***multi push is allowed but multi pop is not allowed.***

Comment: Multiple pop can be simulated by adding additional states to keep track of the pop-ed symbols.

Comment: For every second $a$ that you read, push $BBB$ into the stack.

Comment: my stack alphabet is a single character, i tried to simulate k multi-pop by adding k additional state, i use epsilon transitions between these states and pop per each state. i guess it should work. thanks for the tip

Comment: @YuvalFilmus exactly what i need thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every second $a$ that you read, push $BBB$ into the stack.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution. For every $aa$ you could check every $bbb$(skips first $b$, keep stack's present top $a$ as it is and pop $2a$ against for last $2b$).